# Permission failed when creating package using Duplicator Plugins for WordpPress

Tags: wordpress

[Images of this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x88bX.jpg)

When i accessed the wordpress folder, i didn't see any folder or files named wp-snapshot. What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

run this command, it must work

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

Change CHMOD 777 --> folders for creating package :

```
 /wordpress
 /wordpress/wp-snapshot
 /wordpress/wp-snapshot/tmp
```

Don´t forget change again permissions : folders --> CHMOD 644

Please , create folders wp-snapshot - wp-snapshot/tmp If these folders are not created.

With User SSH execute commands :

```
           chmod -R 775 wp-snapshots && chmod 775 ./
```

Comment: So i did chmod 777 for my wordpress folder and re-install Duplicator again but it still didn't work. There was no file or folder name wp-snapshot in my wordpress folder. I really do'nt understand.

Comment: Please Execute chmod with user SSH , review my edit.

Comment: The point is when i tested this on Centos6, there was no problem. I didn't even to chmod 777 or sth, just install plugins and it automatically created the wp-snapshots folder and passed the permissions.
But in case of centos7, it failed all the time. FYI, i'm running Wordpress on my instance Amazon EC2 so i could login to my server through software like tera temp and did what you say bit it still failed.